# :target not working on previous element

Tags: html, css

I have two images

```
<div class = "main-container">
        <div  class="img" id = "one">
            <a href="#one"><img src="1.jpg" ></a>
        </div>

        <div class="img" id = "two">
            <a href="#two"><img src="2.jpg"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

when I click to first image, second should rotate and it is working, but when second image is clicked first one not rotating, however it cames to it's initial position. Only css was used:

```
#one:target ~ #two{
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -355deg );
}
#two:target ~ #one{
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -355deg );
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 2):

- [**General sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

  > The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
  >   element only if it is **preceded by the first**, and both share a common
  >   parent.

---

`#two` is preceded by `#one`, this will work:

`#one:target ~ #two {}`

---

`#one` is not preceded by `#two`, this will **not** work:

`#two:target ~ #one {}`

---

Simply invert the fragment identifiers value  in the anchor's `href` attribute and remove the general sibling selectors.

```css
#one:target {
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-355deg);
}
#two:target {
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-355deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="img" id="one">
    <a href="#two">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="img" id="two">
    <a href="#one">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```